# Get current grid name

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

How do we get Current grid name in our `grid.phtml`

I want to check whether we are on sales order grid or not.

```
if(Sales_order_grid){

Do some Action
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($this->getNameInLayout()=='sales_order.grid'
){

Do Your action;

}
```